# Create a copy of the binary search tree and display it in the TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

You need to create a binary search tree, and then copy the tree and display in the TreeView.
  tree creation method

```
public DTreeNode Created(DTreeNode root,char temp, int nums) //temp - information field, nums - key
   {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new DTreeNode(temp, nums);
            root.Left = null;
            root.Right = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nums < root.Key)
            {
                root.Left = Created(root.Left, temp, nums);
            }
            else
            {
                root.Right = Created(root.Right, temp, nums);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Methods for outputting a tree in TreeView

```
public void Show(TreeView tree, DTreeNode root)
    {
        tree.Nodes.Clear();
        if (root != null)
        {
            tree.Nodes.Add(root.Info + "  (" + root.Key + ")");
            KLP(tree.Nodes[0], root.Left);
            KLP(tree.Nodes[0], root.Right);
        }
    }
    public void KLP(TreeNode node, DTreeNode place)
    {
        if (place != null)
        {
            TreeNode branch = node.Nodes.Add(place.Info + "  (" + place.Key + ")");
            KLP(branch, place.Left);
            KLP(branch, place.Right);
        }
    }
```

But how to copy a binary search tree and display it in a TreeView I don’t know. Please help, I can’t do it already 5 days. All work is done in Windows Forms.

Comment: It is not a C code.

Comment: "You need to...". Um, no. I think that is you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because StackOverflow is not a code writing or homework answering service.